# Best way to store data for a game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I am looking for the best way to store data in a game. Currently I have like 30 different variables which do different things in my game. **I only need these variables to be remembered for when the app is open, once it closes all of these variables get reset**. The way I was doing it currently, was using NSUserDefaults but it just gets too confusing and annoying at this point.

Can anyone tell me how I should go upon this? And if so, a link on how to do it would be helpful too!

Comment: Variables remain in memory while your app is running; you don't need to "store" them unless you want them to persist _between_ runs. What difficulty are you having?

Comment: agree with @Josh Caswell .create Singleton to store upon runtime.

Comment: Right now I am keeping all of my variables in a Singleton but it seems that these variables do not get 'remembered' but if I do it via NSUserDefaults it works fine.

Comment: If they are not getting 'remembered' then you are releasing them at some point during the game. Either your game logic is flawed or your singleton logic is flawed. There is no need to write to disc (NSUserDefaults) to persist variables during a session.

Comment: Implement NSCoding for your Singleton and save/load it when app exit/start.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seemed that my Singleton logic was wrong, I am rethinking it now and it should work!

Comment: Also just to be clear, when I set (lets say a BOOL) in the applicationDidFinishLaunching, that BOOL's value will be remember ALL THE WAY until the app closes. That is correct, right?

Comment: Depends on what the variable is. Without you posting some code and explaining your expected and actual results, this isn't going to go very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your variables in your `appdelegate`class.
As the scope of your `appdelegate` class is through out your application and when you want to use those variables you can just share them with different class.

And as your requirement is that the variables needs to be remembered once, this approach will do exactly the same and as soon your app is close the scope of `appdelegate` will be over too and thus they will get released and when you launch your game again they will surely fetch new value.:)

Comment: I didn't down vote but as far as i know, you are not supposed to use the app delegate to hold data.

Comment: I have to accept your answer anyway otherwise I will get penalized so you may want to re-word your answer otherwise you might get others who stumble upon this question confused.